# Selecting first row with groupby and NaN columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select the first row of each group of a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = [{"id": "a", "val": np.nan, "val2": -1}, {"id": "a", "val": "TREE", "val2": 15}]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)


#   id   val  val2
# 0  a   NaN    -1
# 1  a  TREE    15
```

When I try to do this with `groupby`, I get

```
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
#   id   val  val2
# 0  a  TREE    -1
```

The row returned to me is nowhere in the original data frame. Do I need to do something special with NaN values in columns other than the groupby columns?

Comment: ``df.groupby('id').head(1)`` might be more what you are looking for

Comment: This is actually a bug: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8427. First is working by design (it skips nans), but its doing it column by column (as you have multi-dtypes) and thus skips in one column but not another. Have to rework this a bit I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the following that appears to be a workaround on the [Pandas github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6732) site.  Uses the `nth()` method
instead of `first()`

```
     df.groupby('id', as_index=False).nth(0,dropna=False)
```

I didn't dig into it much.  It seems odd that `first()` would actually use the `val` from a different row but I haven't actually found the documentation on first to check if this is by design.